# I have image folder and a csv file(has [0]every image name and [1] Labels

Tags: csv, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have two separate image folders (Test and train): Have 6 categories
Also have labels (2 seperate csv file)
Those csv file has 1st column: image name and 2nd column has labels.
I need help (sample code) to make the dataset as input in a CNN model.

Comment: please take the [tour] and review [ask] and [mre]. what language, what libraries?

Answer (score 0):

assume your csv files are called train.csv and test.csv and both reside in a directory sdir as do the Test and train folders. Is it correct to assume that train.csv has the relative filepaths to the train files and test.csv has the relative paths to the test files? I will proceed under that assumption where the csv files have 2 columns labeled 'filepaths' and 'labels'.  so try this

```
train_dir=os.path.join(sdir,'train')
train_csv_path=os.path.join(sdir, 'train.csv')
train_df=pd.read_csv(train_csv_path)
test_csv_path=os.path.join(sdir, 'test.csv')
test_df=pd.read_csv(train_csv_path)
test_dir=os.path.join(sdir, 'test')
batch_size=20
img_size=(224,224)
gen=Image_Data_Generator(rescale=1/255, preprocessing_function=scalar,validation_split.=.2)
train_gen=gen.flow_from_dataframe(train_df, directory=train_dir, x_col='filepaths', y_col='labels', shuffle=True,
                                 target_size=img_size, class_mode='categorical', batch_size=batch_size, subset='training')
valid_gen=gen.flow_from_dataframe(train_df, directory=train_dir, x_col='filepaths', y_col='labels', shuffle=True,
                                 target_size=img_size, class_mode='categorical', batch_size=batch_size, subset='validation')
test_gen=gen.flow_from_dataframe(test_df, directory=test_dir, x_col='filepaths', y_col='labels', shuffle=False,
                                 target_size=img_size, class_mode='categorical', batch_size=batch_size)                                
# then build you model

history=model.fit(train_gen, verbose=1, validation_data=valid_gen, epochs=20)

acc=model.evaluate(test_gen)[1]* 100
print (acc)
```